# '90s or 2000s anime - high school friends trying to save their friend (girl) who is stuck in dangerous dimension

Tags: story-identification, anime

I've been looking for this anime for a while now. It is about a group of friends in high school. One of the boys is quite smart at coding and is trying to get their friend (a girl) out from another dimension, where she is stuck.

In the dimension she has to hide and fight to survive from robots. They have red lasers as eyes and run super fast on stick like legs. The girl is very weak and they are desperate to save her.

I also think they are trying to close some kind of portal to save the world from the robots.

Comment: the girl stuck in the dimension tended to blush a lot and her head was mostly bowed down because she was so weak. her clothing was mostly pink. The boy coding was always stressed and he was in love with her. sometimes she would enter a room that completely empty and in there they could communicate with her and their voices would echo through the void. also i think they used their lockers as portals sometimes. the graphics were a bit more modern (3d)

Comment: That comment should be part of the question. You can always [edit] it in.

Comment: "the girl stuck in the dimension tended to blush a lot and her head was mostly bowed down because she was so weak. her clothing was mostly pink." okay, that rules out *Suzumiya Haruhi*.

Answer (score 14):

While this is tropey, it could match *Code Lyoko* (2003). It's a French cartoon though, not an anime.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_Lyoko):

> **Jeremy Belpois, a 12-year-old prodigy** attending boarding school at Kadic Academy, **discovers a quantum supercomputer in an abandoned factory near his school.** Upon activating it, **he discovers a virtual world called Lyoko with an artificially intelligent girl named Aelita trapped inside it.** Jeremy learns of X.A.N.A., a fully autonomous, malevolent, and highly intelligent multi-agent system, that also dwells within the Supercomputer. Using Lyoko's powers, X.A.N.A can possess electronics and objects in the real world like a virus to wreak havoc. X.A.N.A.'s primary objective is to eliminate anyone aware of the Supercomputer's existence so that it will be free to conquer the real world and destroy all humanity.
>
> **Jeremy works tirelessly to materialize Aelita into the real world and stop attacks caused by X.A.N.A. Jeremy is aided by his three friends** Odd Della Robbia, Ulrich Stern, and Yumi Ishiyama, **who are virtualized into Lyoko to save both worlds from the sinister virtual entity.**

Pink-themed Aelita can be seen at 0'35 in the opening

The monster could be any one in these... Krabs and tarantulas both have long legs, and all have X.A.N.A.'s target symbol as their "eye":

[image: all monsters from the show, including mantas, William, Krabs, tarantulas]

Comment: If this is the right answer, you can accept it by clicking the checkmark on the left.